# Databinding with WPF User Control

Tags: wpf, data-binding, user-controls

I've been Googling for it; but without any luck.  I think this is fairly simple.

I have a user control named `TicketGroup`.  `TicketGroup` is the visual representation of a List object I have.  The XAML code I've got looks like this.

```
    <c:TicketGroup Grid.Row="1" />
    <c:TicketGroup Grid.Row="2" />
    <c:TicketGroup Grid.Row="3" />
    <c:TicketGroup Grid.Row="4" />
```

Inside the `TicketGroup` I have an `ItemsControl` called `TicketItemsControl` and it has an `ItemsSource =""` attribute in there.  What I'm struggling to do is 'pass in' that `ItemsSource` value in the above XAML.

Basically, the object I'm working with has four different lists.  I want the first `TicketGroup` to have an `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyList1}"` and the second to have an `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyList2}"` etc.... but I can't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the datacontext of each c:TicketGroup to the List so you will have code like:

```
<c:TicketGroup Grid.Row="1" DataContext="{Binding Path=MyList1}" />
<c:TicketGroup Grid.Row="2" DataContext="{Binding Path=MyList2}" />
<c:TicketGroup Grid.Row="3" DataContext="{Binding Path=MyList3}" />
<c:TicketGroup Grid.Row="4" DataContext="{Binding Path=MyList4}" />
```